# Reading a character and a hexadecimal value from a file in C++

Tags: c++, hex, file-handling

My file is like

```
k FFFFFFFF
s FFFFFFFF
t FFFFFF
```

I want to read the each character and its hex value  from the file and process it and then go to the next. how do I go about

Comment: read the hex part into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and then convert it using [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet that you're having a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `std::hex` I/O manipulator and follow the normal "read a file" formula.

Example, reading your input format from stdin:

```
int main() {
    char c = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    std::cin >> std::hex; // Read hexadecimal integers
    while (std::cin >> c >> i)
    {
        std::cout << "c: " << c << ", i: " << i << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Output for your sample input:

```
c: k, i: 4294967295
c: s, i: 4294967295
c: t, i: 16777215
```

Comment: So the hexadecimal value is associated with the variable i here, I have hexadecimal values like FFFFFFF ( seven FFF's) and FFFFFF( six FFF's) but my max is FFFFFFFF( eight FFF's).. I want to do the processing in the while loop i.e convert the hexadecimal to binary with each element of binary in an array of size 32 ( since I have max 8 F's) but also to append the top part of my array with zeros if there are less than 8 hex characters..